# Black Screen, problem

Tags: gnome, compiz

I'm having problems with Ubuntu since a couple of days. I have GNOME-compiz for the desktop configuration and windows effects (not a big deal, small changes).

When I use Google Chrome, and I enter mostly to YouTube to reproduce a video, sometimes in a matter of seconds, screen goes to black, but the sound keep going. Then I just close the laptop until the sound mutes, and then I reopen it again. But when I open the laptop, everything goes back normally, but for the exception that taskbar (upper and lower) of gnome and buttons like (switch off, date, WIFI) doesn't show. So the only thing to do is to press Ctrl+Alt+Super and close session.

How can I fix these problems of my laptop crushing in video on those times I open YouTube (This doesn't happen every times, just sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

When ever you are loading or opening a YouTube video it will load flash player. If that player is having any issues then there is a probability for getting for the hang. Try removing the flash player and reinstall it once and check.

Comment: I did it and still with the problem.